# Coredump GDB "Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC"

Tags: c, gdb, coredump, toolchain, backtrace

While trying to analyse the backtrace of a coredump (process dumped by a SIGABRT from assert) in GDB I get the following output:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76d6bc54 in raise () from ./lib/libc.so.1
#1  0x76d63bb8 in abort () from ./lib/libc.so.1
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
(gdb) thread apply all bt
```

The binary is compiled with "-g" so are all linked libraries except the ones from the toolchain (e.g. libc which doesn't even have symbols) of which I can't determine how it was built.

Is this stack corruption or is it consequence of libc being compiled with something like "fomit-frame-pointer".

As a general question if an uncaught exception happens from a runtime linked library and that library wasn't built for debug what happens i.e. can the coredump still contain useful information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the culprit was the libc the application was loading. It was probably compiled with some options that made the coredump useless. What I did was create a custom toolchain (used one compiled from buildroot) and compiling and running the application with that toolchain. I then was able to successfully read the coredump.

Comment: Thank you for this precious answer. I stumbled upon the same issue. The culprit is indeed libc.so. I recompiled glibc with -g flag and used this libc version - this solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve a backtrace which includes functions from shared objects without debug symbols is to install debug symbols where gdb can see them. The details of how to do that depend on your environment. One example is that if `libc.so.6` is provided by the `libc6` package on a Debian system, installing the `libc6-dbg` package places a number of symbol tables underneath `/usr/lib/debug/.build-id` (the `libc6` package, in addition to `libc.so.6`, provides a number of other stripped shared objects). If you're using a debugger environment for a non-native core (as suggested by the leading `.` in `./lib/libc.so.1`) you might extract such a package rather than installing it (on a Debian system `dpkg -x` is one way to do that).

Aside from the issue of debug symbols, in some cases you can improve a backtrace by insuring that the shared objects (stripped or otherwise) seen by gdb correctly correspond to the shared objects which were in use by the process which dumped the core. One way to check that is to compare build IDs, which are (on a typical Linux system) reported by the `file` command. This only helps if you can reliably determine which shared objects were in use at the time of the core dump, and it presumes your shared objects were built in such a way that they include build IDs.

In some situations the build IDs of the executable and all of the relevant shared objects can be reliably extracted from the core file itself. On a Linux system, this requires the presence of a file note in the core, and the presence of the first page of the executable and each shared object. Recent Linux kernels configured with typical defaults include all of those.

https://github.com/wackrat/structer provides python code which extracts build IDs from a core file which satisfies its assumptions. Depending on how big the core file is it might be preferable to use a 64 bit system, even if the core itself came from a 32 bit system.

If it turns out that gdb is using the correct shared objects for this core (or if there is no viable way to confirm or refute that), another possibility is to disassemble code in the two stack frames reported by gdb. If the shared objects gdb sees are not the right ones for this core, that disassembly is likely to be mysterious, because gdb relies on the contents of the shared objects it uses to line up with the contents of that location at the time the core file was dumped (readonly segments are typically excluded from the core file, with the exception of that first page which provides each build ID). In my experience gdb can typically provide a coherent backtrace without debug symbols even without a frame pointer, but if the wrong shared object is used, gdb might be basing its backtrace on instructions which do not correspond to the correct contents of that location.

Comment: Thanky Erik. I wasn't aware you could recover the shared objects from a coredump, that means the heap is also dumped? I tries running structer but for some reason I ran into an [exception](https://hastebin.com/wudewixoko.sql)

Comment: The exception in the structer code is due to an unrecognized segment type in the core file's auxv; structer.elf.enums.PType would need to change to handle it, and there is also room for improvement in the exception handling code.